# How to send credit card number in selenium using sendKeys() on a website which accepts credit card field only as number field?

Tags: string, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a page and one of the attributes is the credit card field. It accepts only numbers as input, not a string.
I know the sendKeys() method sends the value in string format. Is there any way to enter a numeric value into the credit card field?

I have tried all the methods and none is working.
Below code

```
WebElement cardnumber = driver.findElement(By.id("card_id"));
cardnumber.sendKeys("41111111111111");
```

Comment: _It accepts only numbers as input, not a string_: Can you update the question with the relevant HTML of the element?

Comment: What is the error that you've get with line `cardnumber.sendKeys("41111111111111");` ?